# VBA: Isolate a decimal number from a string so that I can add or subtract from it

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to write a program that involves finding strings with numerical values that are +1 and -1 from the numerical value located within another string. (The rest of the program is fine, it's just this section that I'm having a difficult time with).

For example:

If I have the parent string: name[CE18.2]-abritraryinfo

I need to find a way to isolate that 18.2 so that I can add 1 to it and subtract 1 from it to create two new numerical values of 19.2 and 17.2

I need to be able to do this in such a way that I can find this number in strings whose 'name' section and whose number after CE vary according to the different parent strings.

What I've tried already is this:

```
'''

Result = Empty 'Resets the value of the result after it changes to the next name

f = InStr(c, "CE") 'Finds at which position in the string CE is located. The position is the C of CE

z = Mid(c, f, 8) 'Pulls 8 units from the string starting at the position dictated by f

stringLength = Len(z) 'Gives the Length of the section pulled by Z

For i = 1 To stringLength 'From the first position to the final position

    If IsNumeric(Mid(z, i, 1)) Then
    Result = Result & Mid(z, i, 1) 'Gives the numbers in the string section pulled by Z

End If
Next i

'''
```

but it doesn't work as it ignores the decimal point.

Any advice would be incredibly helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the digits you need *always* enclosed between `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution is:

```
Sub test1()
    inputS = "name[CE18.2]-abritraryinfo"
    pos = InStr(inputS, "[CE")
    If pos > 0 Then
        x = Val(Mid(inputS, pos + 3))
        Debug.Print x, x - 1, x + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 18,2          17,2          19,2
```

Answer (score 0):

### String Between Two Strings

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub gsbtsTEST()
    
    Const lStr As String = "CE"
    Const rStr As String = "]"
    Const sString As String = "name[CE18.2]-abritraryinfo"
    
    Dim ResString As String
    ResString = GetStringBetweenTwoStrings(sString, lStr, rStr)
    
    Dim ResValue As Double
    If IsNumeric(ResString) Then
        ResValue = Val(ResString)
    End If
    
    Debug.Print ResString, ResValue - 1, ResValue, ResValue + 1
    
End Sub

Function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings( _
    ByVal sString As String, _
    ByVal lStr As String, _
    ByVal rStr As String, _
    Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) _
As String
    
    Dim lPos As Long: lPos = InStr(1, sString, lStr, CompareMethod)
    If lPos = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim rPos As Long: rPos = InStr(1, sString, rStr, CompareMethod)
    If rPos = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    lPos = lPos + Len(lStr)
    
    If lPos < rPos Then
        GetStringBetweenTwoStrings = Mid(sString, lPos, rPos - lPos)
    End If

End Function
```